# Icons on the Launcher stay inactive for a bit after the app is launched

Tags: unity, launcher

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with desktop environment unity. I can put any application I want on the Launcher (the bar which is by default on the left side of the screen). I can then click on it and launch the executable.

However after I launch the executable, the icon stays inactive for roughly 12 seconds. If you set the "pulsating" animation you will see it pulsating but you'd be unable to click it. After that time has passed, it goes back to normal and you can click and open it again.

This is somewhat frustrating if, e.g., you want to open multiple instances of the same app or your app crashes at startup and you want to restart it immediately.

Comment: You have tagged Unity but standard 18.04 is Gnome. Have you changed the environment? I have been using the default Gnome desktop in 18.04 LTS with no issue like this whatsoever.

Comment: Correct, this does not happen on gnome. I have indeed changed the environment to unity.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the change to Unity if the problem goes away when using the default Gnome environment or is it just a choice thing.

Comment: Just a choice. It's not super important, but if I can I'd like to keep unity. If not, I'll consider switching back. I'm asking here precisely to know if there a way to fix it or not.